# Concatenate string with literals in bash shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying (and failing) to concatenate a string variable with a literal

```
a=000
file_name="my_file"$a".txt"
echo $file_name
```

How can I get filename to be `my_file000.txt`?

Comment: "my_file$a.txt"

Comment: What shell are you using, and what error or output do you get instead? This works as expected on my GNU bash 5.0.17 and on my sh -> dash 0.5.10.2.

Comment: My apologies. I realized my mistake which was  a typo.

Comment: Variables are expanded when enclosed in double-quotes, so `ile_name="my_file${a}.txt"` is fine. You are required to guard your variable with `${..}` when the character that follows the variable could be part of the variable name. `'.'` can't so the guard is optional here (never hurts)

Comment: @KansaiRobot : Works for me, though it is written a bit too cumbersome for my taste.  You could have simply written `file_name=my_file"$a".txt`